# Having children in Islam/quran

Tags: practical-islam, children, fard, wajib, birth-control

Is having children in islam farz/wajib if you are married to a woman? Does Quran say anything about it?

Comment: Quran says Allah may give you (only) male children, (only) female children, from both kinds and maybe no children. Having children is considered as something "a gift of God" if you refuse -while Allah may make it possible-  you may sin especially if your spouse wants to have children.

Comment: We are waiting a baby.  i was just courious about the ruling. :)

Comment: We have questions on birth control on the site. So please make clear what exactly you want to know. AFAIK there's no ruling about that stated in the quran, however scholars may deduce more than I would be able to do.